# How to centralize logs of some specific service controlled by systemd

Tags: logs

I deployed some process, which is managed by `systemd`. After executing `systemctl start my-service`, I can see it runs as expected and `journalctl -u my-service` shows me the logs of the process.

Now I deploy the process on many machines of Centos7, and I'm trying to centralize all of logs of the processes to one log machine.

Is there some tool to do so?

Attention, I only want to centralize the logs of the processes, other logs must be ignored, meaning that other logs must stay on their local machines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I send systemd logs to a dedicated logging server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394822/how-should-i-send-systemd-logs-to-a-dedicated-logging-server)